# MSBuild PSExec hangs without error while executing batch file

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, tfsbuild, psexec

As part of as our Team Build MSBuild script, we have a deployment batch file which I need to execute on a remote server:

```
<Exec Command="psexec -accepteula \\servername D:\Build_Drop\DeploySites.bat "/>
```

I can confirm it is not permissions or firewall: if the bat command is changed to run iisreset or calc.exe for example, the command will work.

I have tried -s and >nul flags, and also wrapping the batch file in a call to cmd. I have tried with and without quotes around the bat cmd.

All the options I have tried will work fine from the cmd line on the build server, but none will work from within the build script itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the operating system on the target machine? Is UAC enabled?

Also, what happens if you RDP into the build machine and execute this same command "psexec -accepteula \\servername D:\Build_Drop\DeploySites.bat" using the build service account? You should get the same behavior that you get when it run as part of the Team Build. You might get some error messages when you try it in an RDP session that you dont see when it's running as part of the build. Team Build has a habit of "eating" exception messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a -i parameter to psexec seems to have worked.

Oddly, we now get the error message:

```
The command "psexec -accepteula \\server -i cmd /c "D:\Build_Drop\DeploySites.bat"" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
```

But the command does actually work

Comment: Have used the -i parameter and its stopped msbuild psexec hanging, thanks, and it hasn't shown the code 5 error either. We have a number of psexec calls, and when I applied the -i fix to another psexec call I got code 5 error. but for that psexec call on taking out the -i it worked fine. So would suggest use the -i switch only if its hanging. I suspect its to do with the whether the called executable interacts with the console and is then expecting some response from it leading it to hang unless psexec interacts with the console too.